# send raw empty json with GuzzleHttp in laravel

Tags: php, json, laravel, post, guzzle

My solution my be simple but honestly spent almost 5 hour and still not found my answer.
I need Send  request with `Post` and retrieve my data.
With POSTMAN it's work just fine.

[image]

and here my Code

```
use GuzzleHttp\Client;

 $client =new Client();

     $client->post($url,[
            'form_params' => [
              '{}'
            ]
        ]);
```

with `POSTMAN`, I don't need to set `Header` and  all i need to send `{}`.

Get this Error :

```
Client error: `POST http://URL` resulted in a `400 
Bad Request` response: {"error":"Failed when parsing body as json"}
```

Well,How Can I do it now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you want to send your POST data without `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` which is what automatically added by using 'form_params'

If you wish to do this, you should do something more akin to the following:

```php
use GuzzleHttp\Client;
$client = new Client();
$response = $client->post($url, [
    'body' => '{}'
]);
```

Comment: Annoying! Maybe it's not wanting application/json at all! Can you try `$response = $client->post($url, [
    'body' => '{}' 
]);` instead?

Comment: Awesome! I'll update my answer to be what worked for you :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just do

```
$client->post($url,[
    'parameter_one' => $value1,
    'param_two' => $value2,
]);
```

Not sure about how to pass object, i think you can pass PHP object with data as second parameter or array of objects, if you wish..

Comment: first thank for answer. yes i can send parameter like you said but in this specific api i need only send {} and nothing else.